# How to configure wild card ssl in Virtualmin from Lets Encrypt?

Tags: ssl, subdomain, virtualmin

I have setup catchall domain and is has proper DNS and network configuration for subdomains. Next how do I request for wild card ssl with LetsEncrypt in Virtualmin ?

Answer (score 3):

Let's Encrypt only issues wildcard certificates with DNS-01 validation. It means that you cannot validate by just running a HTTP server on the host, but need to modify DNS. If you can modify DNS from virtualmin this is doable. If not, then virtualmin isn't going to be enough.

Comment: My dns records is hosted in the same virtualmin server so virtualmin can modify the dns. Its already using dns based validation. But when I try to add wild card domain *.example.com it says `"Failed to request certificate : A domain name cannot start with *. To create a wildcard domain, first create it without the * and then go to Server Configuration -> Website Options."` but I have already made the domain as match all domain with *.example.com in apache settings

Comment: ***"if you can modify DNS from virtualmin this is doable."*** -  Modify with what? which challenge should I put on  the `TXT` record?